# Generating separate groupby tables for each month in dataframe using for loops or other methods

Tags: python, for-loop, group-by, iteration

I have a pandas dataframe (sample):

```
data = [['ABC', 'John', '123', 'Yes', '2022_Jan'], ['BCD', 'Amy', '456', 'Yes', '2022_Jan'], ['ABC', 'Michelle', '123', 'No', '2022_Feb'], ['CDE', 'John', '789', 'No', '2022_Feb'], ['ABC', 'Michelle', '012', 'Yes', '2022_Mar'], ['BCD', 'Amy', '123', 'No', '2022_Mar'], ['CDE', 'Jill', '789', 'No', '2022_Mar'], ['CDE', 'Jack', '789', 'No', '2022_Mar']]

tmp2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Responsibility', 'Name', 'ID', 'Has Error', 'Year_Month'])

tmp3 = tmp2[['Responsibility', 'Name', 'ID', 'Has Error']]
```

The actual dataframe is a lot larger with more columns, but the above are the only fields I need right now. I already have the following code that generates a year-to-date table that groups by 'Responsibility' and 'Name' and gives me the number & % of unique 'ID's that have errors and don't have errors, and exports the table to a single Excel sheet:

```
    result = pd.pivot_table(tmp3, index =['Responsibility', 'Name'], columns = ['Has Error'], aggfunc=len)
#cleanup
       result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    result.columns = [s1 + "_" + str(s2) for (s1,s2) in result.columns.tolist()]
    result = result.rename(columns={'ID_No': 'Does NOT Have Error (count)', 'ID_Yes': 'Has Error (count)'})
    result = result.astype(int)
#create fields for %s and totals
    result['Has Error (%)'] = round(result['Has Error (count)'] / (result['Has Error (count)'] + result['Does NOT Have Error (count)']) *100, 2).astype(str)+'%'
    result['Does NOT Have Error (%)'] = round(result['Does NOT Have Error (count)'] / (result['Has Error (count)'] + result['Does NOT Have Error (count)']) *100, 2).astype(str) + '%'
    result['Total Count'] = result['Has Error (count)'] + result['Does NOT Have Error (count)']
    result = result.reindex(columns=['Has Error (%)', 'Does NOT Have Error (%)', 'Has Error (count)', 'Does NOT Have Error (count)', 'Total Count'])

#save to excel
    Excelwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('./output/final.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')    
    workbook=Excelwriter.book
    
    result.to_excel(Excelwriter,sheet_name='YTD Summary',startrow=0 , startcol=0)
```

Now, I want to keep this YTD summary sheet, and generate the 'result' table for data from each month (from the 'Year_Month' field in the original dataset tmp2), and export the same table with data for each month into separate Excel sheets within the same output file. I will be generating this entire output file on a recurring basis, so want to write the code so that when I read in a new dataframe, it will automatically identify each month available in the data, and generate separate tables for each month using the code that I've already written above, and export each table into separate tabs in the Excel file. I'm a beginner at Python and I'm finding this is harder to do than I originally thought and what I've tried so far is not working. I know one way to do this would be to use a for loop or matrix functions, but can't figure out how to make the code work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about the year, you can split the month from the last column and then iterate over `groupby`.

1. split the month

```
df['month'] = df['Year_Month'].str.split('_').str[1]
```

2. iterate with `groupby`

```
for month, df_month in df.groupby('month'):
    # your processing stuff here
    # 'df_month' is the sub-dataframe for one month
    df_month_processed.to_excel(ExcelWriter, sheet_name=month, ...)
```